# Getting "Invalid Type: Home__c" on VS Code while trying to deploy a class

Tags: apex, class

So I have followed everything in the tutorials/challenges/projects and have been able to pass every one, however, on this one: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/get-started-with-salesforce-development/write-business-logic-in-apex I am getting some weird warnings on compilation when I replace the code in the HouseService class creation part of the challenge. I have replaced the code for the one on the challenge and I get the following in compilation:

Invalid type: House__c [Ln 4, col 34]

but It should be there because the "House" object is there! As per this image:

[image]

Doesn't that imply/indicate that the House__c object exists and therefore it should be sucessfully and normally referred to by Apex?

Why am I getting this? Where's my error and what am I doing wrong if the problem is on my end?

Here's the code in the HouseService.cls class file the challenge instructs us to add to it:

```
    public with sharing class HouseService {
    @Auraenabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<House__c> getRecords() {
        try {
            //Create a list of House records from a SOQL query

            List<House__c> lstHouses = [

                SELECT

                Id, 
                Name,
                Address__c,
                State__c,
                City__c,
                Zip__c

                FROM House__c
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                ORDER BY CreatedDate
                LIMIT 10
            ];
            return lstHouses;

        }
        //Code to handle exception

        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't it work normally? Whaat am I missing? Please help, I'm stuck here.

Comment: if you go to setup - object manager, can you find the `Home` object there? if so, make sure you are connected to the right org on VS Code

Comment: Do a search in VS Code for `Home__c`. Odds are, you have a stray class or trigger that has the wrong object name. Keep in mind that, by default, all changed files are deployed, so make sure you're looking through other files, not just the one you're deploying.

Comment: @McCubo thanks! I ran the sf org open command on VS code and got this URL: https://brave-goat-o7irsc-dev-ed.trailblaze.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/House__c/list?filterName=Recent which loads directly a list of Recently Viewed House objects instances (just one atm) which I opened in the previous step to make some changes. Which tells me both the Home object is there and I am connected to the right org on VS Code (I compared the link opened with the command, with the one I get by clicking "Launch" on my browser. The links are the same. I was reading and the error seems to be Java related tho

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I have no object named Home__c but rather House__c (I am pretty sure I followed the challenges to the dot but still ran the search to be 110% sure), I have also ran a search for House__c and I got the results of only one object within the project, as well as all of its fields and all, here's an image of the results: https://ibb.co/cgSSnd7.

Not sure where else might I be able to check. As I mentioned on the previous comment, I have compared the links I get with the Launch button on my browser and the one with sf org open command and they're the same. :(